# Mobile app using react-native-cli or expo-cli?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm going to make my first app in React Native. I have windows, but I want to make this app cross-platform. I want to use camera for making short videos (like tiktok) on this app.
Can I make this app using windows? and what I need to use? expo or react-native-cli?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is a question about an opinion. To use the camera you'll need native modules, idk if expo allows that, some time ago didnt allow but idk what is status of expo now. Beyond that, IMHO you could begin with `rn cli` directly because this is the most used in "the real life" and no has a big difference with expo.

Comment: Thank you! But I saw with expo I can review my app on my iphone without emulator. How can I do that with rn-cli? Because I'm using windows I can't have emulator for iOS.

Comment: Yes, you right, the only way to test an app in iphone with rn-cli is have a mac. If you use Win and u have an iphone, so yes, you must go throught expo... I search a little in google and found this article, maybe it will help you:  [https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-camera-app-with-expo-and-react-native/] (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-camera-app-with-expo-and-react-native/)

Comment: One more question, if you can answer me, please. I see that the expo project doesn't have these folders called "android" / "ios" like react-native-cli. What is it about? what those folders do? Thank you!

Comment: No problem, in /android and /ios folder you can find some items like the .apk or .ipa files when you compile, native code of app, files for setting up some packages that need being linked with native part, beside a lot of things that you need when you app start to failed jaj (joke)

Comment: If you want to deep dive you can read this redit question: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/9t5rfj/when_reactnative_generates_an_ios_and_android/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

but for now I dont thing that you need these folders